SCNTransaction won't run on scene load, unless the scene is tapped first
I'm creating a SceneKit programmatically, and I want to focus on all of the nodes that I've added using this method below. And wrapping them inside SCNTransaction to animate the movement.
@objc
func resetCamera() {
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.5
    
    sceneView.defaultCameraController.stopInertia()
    sceneView.defaultCameraController.frameNodes(annotationRootNode?.childNodes ?? [])
    
    SCNTransaction.commit()
}

animation preview
It works wonderfully, however, this codes won't run on initial load. Unless I manually tapped on the screen first.
Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried to put them inside viewDidAppear & dispatchQueue, and this thing still won't run, again, unless I tapped on the screen first.
I have also tried to enable several properties of sceneKit such as isPlaying = true.
I have searched through google, app dev forum, chatGPT, stackoverflow and found nothing about this issue.

How I setup the SceneView
func setupViews() {
    ...
    view.addSubview(viewContainer)
    viewContainer.addSubview(sceneView)
    
    viewContainer.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.edges.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide).inset(Constants.defaultInset)
    }
    
    sceneView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }
    
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.overlaySKScene = annotationScene
    
    sceneView.defaultCameraController.automaticTarget = true
    sceneView.defaultCameraController.delegate = self
    sceneView.defaultCameraController.inertiaEnabled = false
    
    camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true
    camera.orthographicScale = 10.0
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-45.0 * .pi / 180, 45.0 * .pi / 180.0, .zero)
    sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode        
    sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    ...
}

How I setup the scene
func loadAnnotations(with nodes: [NodesData]) {
    annotationRootNode = SCNNode()
    for node in nodes {
        let geometry: SCNGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
        let child: SCNNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        child.name = node.name
        child.position = node.position
        child.position.y = Float(node.level) * 5.0
        
        if levelNodesDict[node.level] == nil {
            let currLevelNode: SCNNode = SCNNode()
            currLevelNode.addChildNode(child)
            levelNodesDict[node.level] = currLevelNode
        }
        else {
            levelNodesDict[node.level]?.addChildNode(child)
        }
    }
    
    for node in levelNodesDict.values {
        annotationRootNode?.addChildNode(node)
    }
    
    if let annotationRootNode {
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(annotationRootNode)
        scene.rootNode.worldPosition = .init(x: .zero, y: .zero, z: .zero)
    }
}


Have you tried starting your animation in override func didMove(to view: SKView)?

Can you post the code you use to setup the SceneView and the Scene?

@DonMag I'm using SceneKit and not SpriteKit, I'm not sure what you mean by that, sorry

@ZAY I've added the codes, I'll upload the full code if needed. Thank you

Initially I thought it might be related to: isPlaying = true - but it seems you already testet that. If you want, you can share me your project, and I'll have a look at it.

@ZAY I've found the root cause while trying to clean up the code to post them publicly . Thank you for your help! I might ask for your help again in the future

congratulation!

Anyway, thank you for the help. I've found the root cause, in case anyone got similar issue.
So, notice that I'm only assign the cameraNode to sceneView.pointOfView, turns out you should also insert the camera to the rootNode.
As for why does it's only work after I tapped the screen, I had no idea.
sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChild(cameraNode)

